# How to get adoquery sort to work correctly

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have just an adoquery and when i try
`adoquery1.sort := 'Cost';`

it does not sort the items in the query.

```
{Gets starting cards and put them into the correct rows}
//***************************************************************************
procedure TFGame.GetStartingCards;
//***************************************************************************
const
  ManaTypes : array [0..3] of string = ('Lava','Water','Dark','Nature');
var
   i: integer;
   z:integer;
   Cards: TObjectList<Tcard>;
begin
  Cards := TObjectList<TCard>.Create(false);
  z:=0;
  {add all tcards (Desgin ) to this list in order Lava,water,dark,nature }
  cards.Add(cardLava1);
  cards.Add(cardlava2);
  cards.Add(cardlava3);


  for i := 0 to Length(ManaTypes) - 1 do
  begin
    with adoquery1 do
    begin
      close;
      sql.Clear;
      sql.Add('SELECT TOP 4 * FROM Cards WHERE Color = "'+ManaTypes[i]+'" ORDER BY Rnd(-(1000*ID)*Time())');
      open;
    end;

      {return the result of everything for giving mana type.. }
     if adoquery1.RecordCount = 0 then
        Showmessage('Error no cards in db');
     adoquery1.Sort := 'Cost';
     adoquery1.First;

     while not adoquery1.Eof do
     begin
        cards[z].Ccost := adoquery1.Fieldbyname('Cost').AsInteger;
    //based on color change background
        cards[z].Background.LoadFromFile(format('%s\pics\%s.png',[maindir,cards[z].Ccolor]));
       adoquery1.Next;
       cards[z].repaint;
       z:=z+1;
     end;
  end;
 cards.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I'd guess you are using Access with cursorlocation clUseServer, if so change to clUseClient.

Comment: Where is `adoquery1.Next` in the `while` loop? does this code even works? how do you know "it does not sort the items in the query"?

Comment: sorry there is a `adoquery1.next` i removed some repeated code and it must of been in there.. I know it works cause i can see the number displayed.

Comment: @Glen, please post code that actually works. there might be issues about the "repeated code" you omitted. and the accepted answer (which is a good alternative) still does not explain why `adoquery1.Sort` did not worked for you. (also when you address someone in the comments please use @user)

Comment: @kobik added the accidentally deleted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adoquery.Sort should work if you set CursorLocation to clUseClient.
The alternative could be changing your query to:

```
Select * from
(
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM Cards WHERE Color = "'+ManaTypes[i]+'" ORDER BY Rnd(-(1000*ID)*Time())
) x
ORDER by Cost
```

which will select 4 random rows and sort these by Cost.

**EDIT**
as follow up to @kobik 's comment:
If you are already using clUseClient and your sort does not seem to work you will have to make  sure the sorting can be interpreted in your intent. If you are using an Wide(String)field it will be sorted as any string (10,8,9). You might either change the field type to int or float, or add an casted field to you query for sorting purpose (CINT(TextFiled) as IntForSort ,CDBL(Textfield) as FloatForSort for Access).
Since this might lead to converting errors if the content of the field can not be casted, so I'd recommend to use the intended field type on design of the table.

Comment: Assuming you are using Access: `SELECT *, CINT(Cost) as CostAsInt
FROM Cards;`

Comment: sorry bummi, i had noticed i was reading it in as a number..so i just switched it to an number collumn in db :D   thanks again!